# Error on VBA Match with If

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, match

Could someone help me find out what is wrong with this VBA Code, please?
In the vba code workbook BASE has more than 3000 items in column A and Each line has a name, for example: "B-Y0011".
I want to search this item in another workbook named in this vba code 'wb'.
BUT this workbook 'wb' has three sheets. I have to find the item in one of these sheets and the line position which the item is on.
It ran one time, but when it doesn't find it, it got an error. And now that I tried to add an ERROR function, it gives me another ERROR.

Thank you so much

```
Sub ATUALIZAR_ALOCACAO()

Dim caminho As String, Dim j As Variant, Dim plan As Variant, Dim plan1 As 
Variant, Dim plan2 As Variant, Dim wb As Workbook, Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

mes = InputBox("Qual o mês que você está consolidando informação de Diesel?")
ano = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE").Range("R1").Value

ind_mes = Application.Match(mes, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE").Range("L:L"), 0)
mes_aloc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE").Range("N" & ind_mes).Value
num_mes = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE").Range("M" & ind_mes).Value

If num_mes < 10 Then
    num_mes_cod = "0" & num_mes
Else
    num_mes_cod = num_mes
End If

caminho = "\\sedenas01\carnaxide\A&CCC\15 - Brasil - Inovação e 
Desenvolvimento\PDCAs\Consumo Diesel\Alocação\2017\" & num_mes_cod & 
".RELAÇÃO DE FROTAS GERAL IC " & mes_aloc & " " & ano & ".xls"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=caminho, ReadOnly:=True)

With wb
    lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        j = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE").Cells(i, 1).Value
        plan = Application.Match(j, wb.Sheets("BETONEIRAS").Range("K:K"), 0)

        On Error Resume Next

        If plan > 0 Then

            wb.Sheets("BETONEIRAS").Range("M" & plan).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE").Range("I" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            wb.Sheets("BETONEIRAS").Range("P" & plan).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE").Range("J" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Else

            plan1 = Application.Match(j, wb.Sheets("BOMBAS DE CONCRETO").Range("K:K"), 0)

            If plan1 > 0 Then

                wb.Sheets("BOMBAS DE CONCRETO").Range("M" & plan1).Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE").Range("I" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                wb.Sheets("BOMBAS DE CONCRETO").Range("P" & plan1).Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE").Range("J" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            Else

                plan2 = Application.Match(j, wb.Sheets("BOMBAS DE CONCRETO").Range("H:H"), 0)

                If plan2 > 0 Then

                    wb.Sheets("PÁS CARREGADEIRAS").Range("J" & plan2).Copy
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE").Range("I" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                    wb.Sheets("PÁS CARREGADEIRAS").Range("L" & plan2).Copy
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE").Range("J" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

End With

wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `If plan > 0 Then` check if it is an error `If Not IsError(plan) Then` do this for all three.

Comment: By using 'On Error Resume Next', you will be ignoring any errors you encounter - and you never reset that. A better approach, for your testing, would be to use an error trap where you could place a breakpoint, examine the error, then resume back at the failing line to find where it happened, then either correct the code if possible, or add some 'If Err.Number = nnn' code in the error trap to handle/ignore the error.

Comment: I would suggest just removing the `On Error Resume Next` as it will not be needed anymore with my suggestion above.

Comment: Thank you a lot!!! it works perfect!